# Unrecognized WebSocket connection option error in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am using socket.io in react native everything goes well except i get this warning in bottom screen in yellow box-
Unrecognized WebSocket connection option(s) `agent`, `perMessageDeflate`, `pfx`, `key`, `passphrase`, `cert`, `ca`, `ciphers`, `rejectUnauthorized`. Did you mean to put these under `headers`?
please help

tried all trouble shooting

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me.

`const socket = io(host, { forceNode: true });`

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1290